# SP13 Capturing Email Address in Survey

Tags: 2013, infopath, form, survey

I created a survey and have the "Created By" column type active.  However, when individuals answer the survey instead capturing just the "created by" field is there a way to capture their email address?  Or create a column type that functions similar to the "people and group" type, however, it captures the email address and not just the name.  I wanted the email address to avoid the possibility of two or more individuals having the same name.  Or, should I create an InfoPath form that functions like a survey, but has a field that operates as "people and group" column.  For an example, please view the illustration below.

[image]

Thank you for your help.  If you need further information, please let me know.

Comment: Are these users actual members of the SharePoint site with Active Directory accounts that store their email address? Or are they anonymous users who fill their name in as part of the survey?

Comment: Great question, @thanby.  The users are actual members of the SharePoint site with Active Directory accounts.  I rather for not the user to fill their email address manual to avoid typo errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your users are registered in AD, SharePoint is already storing their account information including email. If you want it displayed alongside the "Created By" field, a simple workflow will do the trick.

Simply create a text column in the survey to store the email, then use SharePoint Designer 2013 to create a workflow that fires when an item is created. The workflow only needs one action, which is "Update List Item". Click the "this list" link, set it to "Current Item" and add the field you are using to store the email, then click the "fx" button and set the value to data source "Current Item", field from source "Created By", and return field as "Email Address".

Now whenever a user submits a survey, their email address will be recorded in the text field you created.

If you want to make it look really smooth and have that field completely hidden to the user you can just create the survey in InfoPath instead, and use the exact same workflow method to record the email.

Hope that answers your question, let me know if you need any more clarification.
Cheers!

Comment: Awesome @thanby.  Sometimes I forget to utilize Workflows.  However, your way explained is very savvy.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Is the survey need to be created using "Initiation Form Parameters" in SP Designer for this workflow to work?  When creating survey using the survey app and applying the survey I receive an error. The workflow doesn't receive an error in designer.  Thanks for your help.